# Image Rendition not working on SP Page

Tags: picture-library, image-display

I have enabled blob cache on my web app, added new image to the site collection images library, and created a new image rendition, and modified the existing ones to zoom on a specific area of the image, when I apply any of these image renditions to my image in my page, it doesn't zoom to the area I tried to zoom it to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite for Image Renditions are:

- Publishing site collection (or publishing feature enabled)
- A configured BLOB cache
- An Asset Library (recommended)

From your description, I can't read that publishing feature is enabled. [Enable publishing features](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/enable-publishing-features-HA010157772.aspx) to get image renditions to work.

Comment: Publishing feature is SURE enabled, I can access image renditions!! How can I access that feature and use it without publishing feature enabled, no need to state that in my question!

Comment: @SPDev it's hard to tell without more information in your question what could be wrong. But if you follow the steks in my blog post [Manage Image Rendition](http://sharepointonline.se/Blog/Post/4/Manage-Image-Renditions) it should work. The guide have been used by two of my colleagues - whom both successfully implemented image renditions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this solution.

Some Blob cache is buggy and in that case you need to flush it.To flush the Blob cache please run the below mentioned script.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```